# Moving cells in excel formula

Tags: excel

I have a table in excel that I want to verify some %, but the formula goes down in the cell and the table goes to the right.

[image]

There is any way to modify the way the cells in the formula moves?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NlFMa.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an inelegant solution: add an adjacent column of ordinal numbers starting from 1 (1,2,3, etc), and then refer in your formula to (for example):

`=OFFSET($A$2,0,D6)`

Hopefully this picture makes it clearer.

[image]

Comment: You're welcome! Feel free to mark as 'solved' if it works for you :)